# Accessing grouping variables in purrr::map() with nested dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

I'm using `tidyr::nest()` in combination with `purrr::map()` (-family) to group a `data.frame` into groups and then do some fancy stuff with each subset. Consider following example, and **please ignore the fact that I don't need `nest()` and `map()` to do this** (this is an oversimplified example):

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    wt_mean = map_dbl(data,~mean(.x$wt))
  )

# A tibble: 8 x 4
    cyl  gear data               cly2
  <dbl> <dbl> <list>            <dbl>
1     6     4 <tibble [4 x 9]>      6
2     4     4 <tibble [8 x 9]>      4
3     6     3 <tibble [2 x 9]>      6
4     8     3 <tibble [12 x 9]>     8
5     4     3 <tibble [1 x 9]>      4
6     4     5 <tibble [2 x 9]>      4
7     8     5 <tibble [2 x 9]>      8
8     6     5 <tibble [1 x 9]>      6
```

Usually when I do this type of operation, I need access to the grouping variable (`cyl` in this case) within `map()`. But these grouping variables appear as vectors with length corresponding to the number of rows in the nested dataframe, and therefore don't lend themselves easily.

Is there a way I could run the following operation? I would want the mean of `wt` to be divided by the number of cylinders (`cyl`) *per group* (i.e. row).

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl,gear) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    wt_mean = map_dbl(data,~mean(.x$wt)/cyl)
  )


Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Result 1 is not a length 1 atomic vector.
```

Comment: What do you get when you use `map` instead of `map_dbl`? I usually start with the bare `map` for debugging. That error comes when each iteration of `map_dbl` doesn't result in a single numeric value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take `cyl` out of the `map` call:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl,gear) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    wt_mean = map_dbl(data, ~mean(.x$wt)) / cyl
  )

# A tibble: 8 x 4
    cyl  gear data              wt_mean
  <dbl> <dbl> <list>              <dbl>
1     6     4 <tibble [4 x 9]>    0.516
2     4     4 <tibble [8 x 9]>    0.595
3     6     3 <tibble [2 x 9]>    0.556
4     8     3 <tibble [12 x 9]>   0.513
5     4     3 <tibble [1 x 9]>    0.616
6     4     5 <tibble [2 x 9]>    0.457
7     8     5 <tibble [2 x 9]>    0.421
8     6     5 <tibble [1 x 9]>    0.462
```

`map_dbl` sees `cyl` as a length 8 vector because `nest` removes groups from `data.frame`. Using `cyl` in `map_*` function call (as in OP's example) results in 8 length-8 vectors.

### 2 other approaches:

Both with same result as above, but keep the grouped variables in the `map_*` call, per OP's specs:

#### Re grouping after `nest`

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl,gear) %>%
  nest() %>%
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
  mutate(wt_mean = map_dbl(data,~mean(.x$wt)/cyl))
```

#### `map2` for iterating over `cyl`

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl,gear) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(wt_mean = map2_dbl(data, cyl,~mean(.x$wt)/ .y))
```

Comment: Hey Zack, this actually works nicely on this minimal example. The two other approaches you edited (regrouping with `group_by()` and using `map2_*`/`pmap_*`) are actually much more handy in various other scenarios. Would you mind reintegrating these approaches in your answer? (i did state that I need the grouping var *within* the `map()`)

Comment: that you did! I've added them in at the end.

Comment: Thank you! I gladly accept the answer. But I've also filed this as [an issue on github](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/524)

Answer (score 3):

In the new release of `dplyr` [0-8-0](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2019/02/dplyr-0-8-0/), you can now use `group_map`, which I find very handy for this use case. This is [the example](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/524#issuecomment-448936528) by github user @yutannihilation

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  group_map(function(data, group_info) {
    tibble::tibble(wt_mean = mean(data$wt) / group_info$cyl)
  })
```